# $f(x,y)=\frac{x^ay^b}{x^2+y^2}$ differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

One knows that $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{x^2+y^2}$$ is continuous iff $\alpha+\beta>2$.

Is there any condition of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that the previous function is differentiable?